# SQL expected 0 arguments, got 1

Tags: sql-server, go

I'm executing the following stored procedure:

```
rows, err := w.repo.GetConn().Queryx("EXEC [Users].[User_Get] @ids", sql.Named("ids", tvp))
```

And getting the following error:

> SQL: expected 0 arguments, got 1.

What's wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: This would seem to indicate that `[Users].[User_Get]` does not have an argument.  What's the definition of that stored procedure?

Comment: @Martin It works fine via my db client

Comment: @Martin also I have a feeling that it's caused by query parsing - driver doesn't get parameter in query, but got it in args

Comment: @ElykovAlexandr are you using https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb?

Comment: @mkopriva yes, I do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in `driverName` I put `mssql` there instead of `sqlserver`)

Comment: Is the `mssql` driver deprecated?